# Показ уведомления при переходе на другую страницу Vue.js Notification

Tags: vue.js

Использую компонент уведомления [Vue.js Notification](http://vue-notification.yev.io/).
Возможно ли при переходе (использую [vue router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/))на другую страницу:

```
this.$router.push(`/page-1`)
```

показывать уведомление?
Понимаю, что уведомления можно вызвать на текущей странице, может как-нибудь можно передать параметр который будет показывать это уведомление, когда мы перешли с одной страницы на другую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [навигационными хуками](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#%D0%B3n%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).
Добавить в регистрацию роутов следующий хук:

```
const router = new Router({...});
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  if (from.path === "/") return;
  Vue.notify({
    group: "foo",
    title: "Route changed",
    text: `Previous page: ${from.name} Current page: ${to.name}`
  });
});
export default router;
```

Рабочий пример в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-o1h4y?from-embed)

Comment: Великолепное решение! Благодарю за помощь!